# SagePay API - Incorrect request format when creating a transaction

Tags: php, opayo

I'm probably missing something quite simple here... I'm trying to create a new transaction as per the [docs](https://test.sagepay.com/documentation/#transactions) and SagePay says the request format is incorrect, but I can't see what the problem is.

**My request payload looks like this:**

```
{
  "transactionType": "Payment",
  "paymentMethod": {
    "card": {
      "merchantSessionKey": "912164F4-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-BFA64856C7A8",
      "cardIdentifier": "78A8232B-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-90EC65622666"
    }
  },
  "entryMethod": "Ecommerce",
  "vendorTxCode": "1234556",
  "description": "Online payment script.",
  "amount": 99,
  "currency": "GBP",
  "customerFirstName": "Bob",
  "customerLastName": "Smith",
  "customerPhone": "07911883621",
  "billingAddress": {
    "address1": "20 XXXXXX",
    "address2": "XXXXX",
    "city": "XXXXX",
    "postalCode": "XXX XXX",
    "country": "GB",
    "state": ""
  }
}
```

**The response from SayPay looks like this:**

```
{
  "code": 1000,
  "description": "Incorrect request format"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What SagePay integration are you using, I assume it's not the form integration?

Comment: It's the form SagePay hosts. Specific instructions for that are here: https://test.sagepay.com/documentation/#submit-payment-from-your-server

Comment: Sorry, edited the URL.

Comment: I don't believe it's the method whether they host the payment page, this looks like it's the method where you have your own form to enter CC details, so it could be you're posting it to the wrong endpoint?

Comment: @JamieBicknell: I'm using the SagePay hosted form but it only returns a `card-identifier` which I then need to use to create a transaction.

Comment: Josh, how your issue will resolve/